# Find consecutive days with the same value

Tags: sql

My data is in this format

```
CALENDAR    CLIENTID    TOTAL
20170801    1700          2
20170801    1800    
20170801    1900          2
20170801    1990    
20170801    2000          0
20170801    2090          0
20170802    2090          0
20170803    2090          0
```

I am trying to get the minimum `calendar day` when a particular client has 3 consecutive totals of zero. So, in the example above, my output would be `20170801` since client `2090` had a zero `total` on `20170801`, `20170802` and `20170803` days. I have the following query so far, but `a` and `b` counts are not accurate.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY clientid) b  FROM
    (
        SELECT tt.*
           ,(SELECT COUNT(CALENDAR) FROM STATS 
                WHERE total = 0 
            ) AS a
        FROM STATS tt
        WHERE total = 0
    ) t1
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE b >= 3
```

Comment: Can you please explain how do we know which records are *consecutive* ? None of the 3 fields seem to be unique.

Comment: @GMB The `total` is unique (zero) for clientid `2090` which is also unique. I am looking for `20170801` as the output for clientid `2090` because there was a zero total for 3 consecutive days (`20170801`, `20170802`and `20170803`).

Comment: Ahhh ok, sorry, that was clear enough indeed. I think Gordon's answer is the best possible for your use case !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lead()`.  The following query gets all such days, ordered by date:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             lead(total) over (partition by clientid order by calendar) as total_1,
             lead(total, 2) over (partition by clientid order by calendar) as total_2
      from stats s
     ) s
where total = 0 and total_1 = 0 and total_2 = 0
order by date;
```

You can add `fetch first 1 row only` or the equivalent for your database to get only one row.

Answer (score 0):

The way is

```
WITH cte AS (
  Select * From dbo.Consequtive Where TOTAL = 0
  )

SELECT r1.*, r2.*, r3.*
  FROM cte as r1
Left Join cte as r2
  On r1.CLIENTID = r2.CLIENTID and DATEADD(day, 1, r1.CALENDAR)  = r2.CALENDAR
Left Join cte as r3
  On r1.CLIENTID = r3.CLIENTID and DATEADD(day, 2, r1.CALENDAR)= r3.CALENDAR

Where r1.TOTAL = 0 and r2.TOTAL = 0 and r3.TOTAL = 0
```

results in

```
CALENDAR    CLIENTID    TOTAL   CALENDAR    CLIENTID    TOTAL   CALENDAR    CLIENTID    TOTAL
2017-08-01  2090        0   2017-08-02  2090        0   2017-08-03  2090        0
```